# Infinite redirect loop on login after upgrade from Django 3.2 to 4.2

Tags: django, django-authentication

I've just upgraded from Django 3.2 to 4.2. All my tests now pass and `runserver` starts without issues. But then I get an infinite redirection loop when I try to display the home page:

```
[03/Nov/2023 10:52:39] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[03/Nov/2023 10:52:39] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/home/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[03/Nov/2023 10:52:39] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/login/%3Fnext%3D/home/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[03/Nov/2023 10:52:39] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/login/%3Fnext%3D/accounts/login/%253Fnext%253D/home/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[03/Nov/2023 10:52:39] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/login/%3Fnext%3D/accounts/login/%253Fnext%253D/accounts/login/%25253Fnext%25253D/home/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

etc. until the browser detects the loop.

Can anybody encountered this before tell me what is the change from Django 3.2 to 4.2 which causes this? I don't really know where to start looking.

The exact same code base running in a Django 3.2 virtualenv is unbroken.

Comment: Did you define a custom template for the login? Can you share how you registered the views/templates/urls w.r.t. authentication?

Comment: @willeM_Van_Onsem Have found the problem. It was locally written middleware to enforce logins. Commenting it out fixed the problem. I'll post a proper answer when I work out more details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was middleware intended to force logins

I wrote this years ago and anticipated this problem ... then for some reason never got around to acting on my own comment "a bit sloppy" and forgot all about it. Kicking myself.

Posting this just in case anyone else gets similarly bitten. This is almost certainly an example of how NOT to write middleware.

```
class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if getattr(view_func, 'login_exempt', False):
            return

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return

        # You probably want to exclude the login/logout views, etc.
        # infinite recursion likely otherwise! 

        if view_func.__name__ in auth_views.__dir__():  # a bit sloppy ...
            return

        return login_required(view_func)(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
```

Comment: perhaps use `dir(auth_views)`, or do these have an `app_label`/`app_namespace`?